# What code snippet plugins are available for VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, plugins, add-in, code-snippets

I want a code snippet editor for VS2008.

I'd like to just hit a hot key, bring up an editor, type in my snippet, run to my break point and step through.

I don't want to have to create a project, create an [xml file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx), or even have to save my file if I don't want to.

I've looked through [What plugin would you really like to have for Visual Studio 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129015/what-plugin-would-you-really-like-to-have-for-visual-studio-2005-2008) already, but didn't see anything.

Anybody know of an plugin that will allow me to do this?   Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to edit a throwaway code snippet or a reusable Visual Studio snippet, you might be looking for something like [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)...

Answer (score 1):

... or [Snippet Designer](http://codeplex.com/SnippetDesigner).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Snipper](http://www.codeplex.com/Snipper).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any VS add-in for that. I do know why you want this. Sometimes I just want to execute certain logic statements and don't want the hassle of project creation.

My improvised solution is still, have a console project. Place the link to the project on my taskbar's quick-launch. I run my codes from the `main` function and resue it over and over again whenever I need it. The hassle is, I need to delete the codes from the previous one.

The plus point is I get to add reference to non-standard assembly or 3rd party ones.

Comment: I just keep creating console apps.  It doesn't take me long, but good god man, why they heck do I have to do this when Eclipse had this functionality in 2003?!?!?!  ~:-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm resurrecting this question to say that [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/) is probably **the** snippet editor/compiler, these days.
I think it was born to test LINQ expressions against a database, and it's particularly geared towards doing that, but it's good as a generic snippet compiler, too.

There's a free version plus some paid versions that add such niceties as code completion and a debugger.